# Which of these is smaller in size: minuscule or tiny?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

*The edges of the area, where it merged with normal skin, was deep violet and crusty, with hundreds of (?????) dry speckles.*

I want the speckles to be as small as possible, without having to write an essay about their smallness. I have eliminated the other choices of words (small, little etc) and am left with two choices: tiny and minuscule. Which of these (a minuscule speckle and a tiny speckle) would be smaller than the other?

I am aware that most of the time, such subtle differences are not probed in depth by the reader. Here, I am concerned with the impression that the word creates in the mind, not what it specifically means. As in, I want the speckles to *feel* as small as possible, to a general English language reader. I am writing fiction, not a scientific report.

Comment: Phrased as it is, this question is asking for preferences. For me, "minuscule" sounds smaller, but I'm sure there are people who would like "tiny" better.

Comment: As a point of note, there is absolutely nothing wrong with *miniscule,* and it might even be preferred to distinguish "small size" from "lower case letter," which OED gives as the primary definition for *minuscule* (upper-case being *majuscule*). "Extremely small" for *minuscule* is definition B2 in the 2002 OED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be minuscule if the speckles are microscopic. It will be tiny if the speckles are visible to eyes. 
I think there is a spelling error in the subject. It should be minuscule  not miniscule.

You are aware that minuscule and tiny are synonyms. So I did not go into explaining the dictionary meaning. While minuscule is used to describe tiny things, I have never seen tiny is ever used to describe microscopic particles like neurons, microorganisms or DNA. Some common examples of tiny are - tiny flower, tiny baby, tiny bird, tiny tots etc which are visible. I have never seen anybody saying - minuscule flower, minuscule baby or minuscule bird. Similarly minuscule scripts are some letters, not visible to normal eyes.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/minuscule

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I will correct the spellings. :)

Comment: Turns out I've been spelling minuscule wrong all this time!  Thanks @SubitDas!  Although it turns out I'm not alone - it's now spelled "miniscule"  52% of the time, including by newspapers etc.  It's still officially "minuscule" though.  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/minuscule-or-miniscule

Comment: @MaxWilliams  There is no wrong in English in such cases. There is no ultimate authority to dictate it and the dictionary holds both versions.

Comment: @Subit Das Can you please add sources to your answer. Otherwise it reads as just your opinion to the reader. ELU strives to provide objective answers. Also consider if you want to rephrase considering that the dictionary supports both ways of writing minuscule.

Comment: @Helmar it's true that "language is as language does", as Forrest Gump's linguist uncle might have said.  But the dictionaries (at least the top five in the google results for 'minuscule meaning') list "minuscule" as the "official" spelling, and "miniscule" as a variant, and so I'd argue that "minuscule" **is**  more correct. eg http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/minuscule Definitions for "miniscule" tend to say "See *minuscule*"

Comment: @MaxWilliams I don't know about more correct, which one could argue is impossible since correct is usually black and white. I totally agree that it's more common.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, they are synonyms so go with whichever suits you.

To my mind (and that is all that it is) *miniscule* sounds slightly more exotic, perhaps because its multi-syllabic.

If you want the *ultimate* in small you could always go with [Plank-scale](http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/einsteinlight/jw/module6_Planck.htm).

Comment: Can you please add sources to your answer. Otherwise it reads as just your opinion to the reader. ELU strives to provide objective answers.

Comment: Dale M did point out clearly that he is speaking about his mental image of _miniscule_ and _tiny_, and hence he is aware of the subjectivity involved. I was indeed asking for the mental imagery concerning these two words :)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to describe speckles is **tiny**. However, minuscule could be considered smaller.

ODO: [minuscule](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/minuscule)

> Extremely small; tiny

ODO: [tiny](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/de/definition/englisch/tiny)

> Very small

Most people probably consider *extremely* a a higher escalation than *very.* Although, tiny is listed as description of minuscule.

If you have a look at the corresponding [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tiny+speckles%2Cminuscule+speckles%2Cminiscule+speckles%2Ctiny+*_ADJ+speckles%2Cminuscule+*_ADJ+speckles%2Cmniscule+*_ADJ+speckles%2C*_ADJ+speckles&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctiny%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bblack_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbrown_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhite_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdark_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bred_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmall_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Byellow_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bminute_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbrownish_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfine_ADJ%20speckles%3B%2Cc0) there are no hits for minuscule, or miniscule (which is just an old way of spelling it), while tiny is right there in-midst of the most used adjectives with speckles. If you look at the results, you might also consider **fine speckles**.